What is this movie about a crime author's murder?
Two men are alone together in a house. At least one is a fiction author (perhaps they both are, but I do not remember). One man, the older man, lives in this house, and he owns many strange artifacts, such as an all-white jigsaw puzzle.
Together the two men act out scenarios in which the older man kills the younger man, recording these stories to a cassette tape. At the end of the movie, the murder actually does take place, and it is revealed that the victim has already called the police.
The movie is in English. I am not sure of the country or the year. I watched this movie at least 10 years ago.
Disclosure: I originally posted this question to Fluther (before I learned about this site).

Sounds like Sleuth from 1972 with Laurence Olivier and Michael Caine (or its remake).

In England, the Italian English hairdresser Milo Tindle is invited by the successful writer of detective stories Andrew Wyke to visit his isolated house. The lower class Milo is the lover of Andrew's wife, who is used to have a comfortable life, and he intends to marry her. Andrew proposes Milo to steal his jewelry simulating a burglary. Milo would make a fortune selling the jewels to an intermediary; and Andrew would be reimbursed by the insurance company and would not pay alimony.

IIRC it contains an all-white jigsaw puzzle, and it ends like you described. It was also remade in 2007, again with Michael Caine (only this time in the opposite role). Here are both trailers:







That's it all right! Much more complicated than I remember, apparently.
